# Is there a CSS Bounce Transition

Tags: html, css, transition

Hello I wondering if there is a transition to make the purple div (the one that slides down when you hover over the feeling down? picture) bounce when it reaches the end?

here is the code- and [jsFiddlle Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/q3w5pLms/2/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="img">
    <div class="hover"><h2>project 1</h2></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.img {
    width: 457px;
    height: 288px;
    background-image: url("http://i59.tinypic.com/xdulh2.png");
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

h2 {
font-family: avenir;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 40px;
color: #000;
}

.hover {
    position:absolute;
    top:-100%;
    width: 457px;
    height: 288px;
    background: rgba(130,76,158,0.5);
     -webkit-transition:all 1s; 
   
}

.img:hover .hover {
    top:0;   
}
```

an example of the transition i mean you can see here http://www.ollygibbs.com

Comment: Why don't you Google "CSS bounce animation"? Here you go, one of the tutorials http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-bounce-effect/

Comment: First one listed on [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Comment: I have googled that but many different options come up that are extremely confusing to me, the one you sent me doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Itay and @BradChristie, guys she(?)'s asking about a `transition` not an `animation`. If it doesn't exist just point that out, but don't go around just commenting a "google first ask later" almost robot-like response. An animation is **very** different from a transition, and they are used in different contexts aswell.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Transition doesn't have bounce-style timing function, so we have to code it with CSS animation keyframes. The problem here is - how to easily decompose a bouncing ( or any other ) functions into a keyframe series over certain style?

This was the problem I encountered when I build [transition.css](https://loading.io/transition/), so I built a tool "[easing.css](https://loading.io/easing/)" to help me generate keyframes from arbitrary equations.

The idea is simple; say we want to make a bounce effect:

1. we first make a timing function f(t) for our desired effect, such as

   Math.abs(Math.sin(1.2 + (t ** 1.4) * 23)) * ( 1 - t ) ** 2.8
2. according to how the output of this function changes, we sampled this function with different interval from 0 to 1.
3. use the sampled (t, f(t)) pairs to generate the css animation keyframes.
4. apply the result animation when we need a transition.

with the concept above, [easing.css](https://loading.io/easing/) also provides several timing function preset so you can play with. Below is a 15-frames bouncing animations generated via easing.css, you could make it more like a real bounce by increasing the frame count or tweaking the timing function provided:

```
.your-block {
  animation: YourAnimation 2s linear 1s;
}
@keyframes YourAnimation {
  0% { height: 7px; }
  8% { height: 24px; }
  10% { height: 36px; }
  17% { height: 99px; }
  19% { height: 83px; }
  21% { height: 69px; }
  24% { height: 57px; }
  25% { height: 56px; }
  27% { height: 59px; }
  34% { height: 100px; }
  36% { height: 88px; }
  38% { height: 80px; }
  48% { height: 100px; }
  72% { height: 100px; }
  100% { height: 100px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The animate.css library will give you a more complete setup and you can choose and pick the ones you need, but if you must code your own, use this code I included in a **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoravG)**

Basically, you instantiate the bounce effect with the following crossbrowser code. This code establishes the bounce, speed of bounce, and the direction it will bounce. You can choose ease-out if you want to.

Now, Bouncing is a tricky thing. Because it must go up and down until it stops. so the bounces must gradually decrease the height. So, this is why you need @-keyframes, (notice you will need @-webkit-keyframes and @-moz-keyframes, etc for a more complete cross browser development. These keyframes allow you to break the effect at any point. In a bouncing effect in particular, the effect breaks every 10% by reducing it's position in the Y axis (which it means height), until it finally stops.

```
-webkit-animation: bounce 1200ms ease-in;
-moz-animation: bounce 1200ms ease-in;
-o-animation: bounce 1200ms ease-in;
animation: bounce 1200ms ease-in;
```

Hope that helps you.

p.s. my code looks a little buggy but you'll have a good enough start. I added your code in your fiddle to it too

Comment: this code makes sense, and so does your codepen but it still doesn't seem to bounce

Comment: hmmm. it does to me. hover over it a little. Like I said, it is a little buggy. I whipped it out as quickly as I could.

Answer (score 0):

Hey as previous suggested [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) is pretty good with css animations, but to have more control over the animation you can add it with js. You just have to add an small script.

```
$('.img').hover(function(){
    $('.hover').addClass('animated bounceInDown');
}, function() {
    $('.hover').removeClass('bounceInDown');
    $('.hover').addClass('bounceOutUp');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hover').removeClass('animated bounceOutUp');  
 }, 1000);
});
```

Check out this fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/d008fafu/3/)

After that, you just need to play with the values on the .bounceInDown .bounceOutUp keyframes annimation (if you want to).

So that the animation is more or less bouncy

```
@keyframes bounceOutUp {
20% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
         transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
}

40%, 45% {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
}

100% {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -800px, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -800px, 0);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (with jquery) of doing this will be using jQuery .animate and easing plugin.

```
    <div id="example">
        <p class="bounce"></p>
    </div>

    div { 
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px; 
        background: red;
    }

    .bounce {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0px;
        background: rgba(134,12,12,.4);
    }

    $('#example').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $('p').animate(
                { height: "200px" }, 
                1000, 
                "easeOutBounce"
             );
    })
```

[js fiddle example][1]  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/2ra7yumo/2/

It gives you little bit more(or easier) control on the animation.